# flatten a map of map in F#

Tags: collections, f#

I have the following:

```
Map<Instrument, Map<PositionSide, PositionData>>
```

is there a way to flatten this to a:

```
PositionData list
```

without iterating through the 2 maps manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we do not worry about duplicate values from the inner maps, it can be done by treating the maps as sequences. Their in-built `GetEnumerator()` method returns a sequence of the type `System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<_,_>`.

The latter can be deconstructed by F#'s predefined active recognizer `KeyValue`.

```
Map.empty<Instrument, Map<PositionSide, PositionData>>
|> Seq.collect (fun (KeyValue(_, v)) -> v)
|> Seq.map (fun (KeyValue(_, v)) -> v)
|> Seq.toList
// val it : PositionData list = []
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it is not possible. There are many issues with it

- at first this are not 2, but potentially many collections in another collection.
- `Map` is not built for iteration, it's dictionary like. But you can convert it to a `List` of pairs first with `Map.toList`
- there is no other possibility than iterate over values if you need them all.

```ml
let toValuesList map = 
    map 
    |> Map.toList 
    |> List.map snd

let ds = 
    data 
    |> toValuesList 
    |> List.collect toValuesList
```

If you could lookup `PositionData` by some key you would at most avoid iterating internal `Map`'s

```ml
let data = 
    map 
    |> toValuesList 
    |> List.map (fun valueMap -> lookupWithin valueMap)
```